# iOS switch from a UIView to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, button, uiview, uiviewcontroller

this is my problem.
I am in a UIView which contains a button. I would like that pressing this button appear the next UIViewController. How can I do?

Comment: I tried this, but without success:

`UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

NextViewController *nextViewController =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Next"];

PreviousViewController *previousViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Previous"];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:previousViewController];

nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[nav pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at some tutorials how to work with `UIButton` and `UINavigationController`. You can find some code in SDK or just Google 2 requests: "UIButton tutorial" and "UINavigationController" tutorial.